# Как перенести строку?

Tags: html

Я хочу сделать надпись в поле, чтобы пользователь ее не мог трогать и не хочу добавлять новый div. Проблема в том, что строка большая, а мне надо ее перенести, как это сделать?

```
<input type="text" class="parent_warning" placeholder="......"  disabled>
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `<input>` используйте `<textarea disabled="disabled">` и ставьте ему какой хотите стиль.